# Conforming to generic protocol method returning PATs

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, pats

I'd like to declare generic protocols similar to the following:

```
protocol Factory {
    func createWidget<T, TWidget>(_ t: T) -> TWidget 
    where TWidget: Widget, TWidget.T == T
}

protocol Widget {
    associatedtype T
    func get() -> T
}
```

I'm hoping that I can implement concrete variations of `Factory` returning  their own concrete and opaque `Widget` with a hidden implementation.

Here's an example implementation that fails to build:

```
struct ConcreteFactory: Factory {
    func createWidget<T, TWidget>(_ t: T) -> TWidget 
    where TWidget: Widget, TWidget.T == T {
        // This line has an error…
        return ConcreteWidget(widgetValue: t)
    }
}

struct ConcreteWidget<T>: Widget {
    let widgetValue: T

    init(widgetValue: T) {
        self.widgetValue = widgetValue
    }

    func get() -> T {
        return widgetValue
    }
}
```

However, this does not compile.

At the line indicated, Swift's compiler give the error "Cannot convert return expression of type 'ConcreteWidget' to return type 'TWidget'".

I also tried having `ConcreteFactory` return a `ConcreteWidget`, but then the error is that `ConcreteFactory` doesn't conform to `Factory`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can’t work. When you *call* your `createWidget` method you specify two types `T` and `TWidget`.

```
struct MyWidget: Widget { 
   func get() -> Int { ... }
}

let widget: MyWidget = factory.createWidget(12)
```

In this Example `TWidget` is `MyWidget` and `T` is `Int`. And this shows nicely why your approach can’t work. You cannot assign a `ConcreteWidget<Int>` to a variable of type `MyWidget`.

What you need is a *type-eraser* for your widgets. Currently you have to write that yourself, but in the future the compiler will hopefully generate them automatically when needed.

```
struct AnyWidget<T>: Widget {
    private let _get: () -> T

    init<Other: Widget>(_ other: Other) where Other.T == T {
        _get = other.get
    }

    func get() -> T {
        return _get()
    }
}
```

This allows you to write your factory protocol and implementation:

```
protocol Factory {
    func createWidget<T>(_ t: T) -> AnyWidget<T>
}

struct ConcreteFactory: Factory {
    func createWidget<T>(_ t: T) -> AnyWidget<T> {
            return AnyWidget(ConcreteWidget(widgetValue: t))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sven! … I've gone for implementing `AnyWidget` with: `struct AnyWidget<Underlying: Widget>: Widget {… let underlying: Underlying …}`. It forwards all `Widget` concerns to it. … Hah hah … and about 2 minutes later, I start to see the issue with this is it's kind of awkward as you need to provide the underlying kind of `Widget` to make use of it. Is there a way to make this approach work? I'm not sure it actually manages to erase any types though!

Comment: :-) I'm pretty sure there's no way to make my approach work, so I've gone with yours completely. Thanks.